# Unzip a file using Foundation

Tags: ios, swift, zip

I found [this](https://recoursive.com/2021/02/25/create_zip_archive_using_only_foundation/) article on zipping a directory using `NSFileCoordinator`, without any third party frameworks.

While this approach works, how can we unzip an archive without using third party libraries? I've tried searching for it, but found no solution. If this task isn't possible, is there any documentation/evidence that highlights the same?

Comment: Third-party libraries are created by people, which means you can write "unzipping" code yourself, without third-party frameworks. :) As stated by an Apple engineer on the Apple Developer Forums (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694893), there's no simple native solution, so you need to write your own or rely on an existing third-party one.

Comment: @lazarevzubov makes sense. If you add it as an answer, I’ll mark it accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third-party libraries are created by people, which means you indeed can write "unzipping" code yourself, without third-party frameworks. :)

As stated by an Apple engineer on the Apple Developer Forums, [there's no simple native solution](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694893) (like a method somewhere in the Foundation framework or somewhere else), so you need to write your own or rely on an existing third-party library. (The answer on the forum was also marked as recommended by Apple.)